# Creating API on same domain used by AWS CloudFront

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a React website being served by AWS CloudFront and S3. I want a contact me section which sends details to an API using API gateway and Lambda.

Is it possible to setup the API endpoint to be on the same domain used by cloudfront?

For example:

```
POST www.example.com/contact-us --> API gateway --> Lambda
www.example.com/* --> Cloudfront --> S3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge optimized API gateway also use CloudFront basically and you can't have same domain name with CloudFront and API gateway but you could define API gateway as an origin of CloudFront and cache behaviour with path e.g: /contact-us and can trigger API gateway, if not, you could write js to trigger the API GW endpoint (aws dns name) directly from contact-us page.

Comment: Thanks James, I think I prefer the former option. So if I create a new stage (e.g. https://xyz.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/api), I can use https://xyz.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com as the Origin Domain Name, /api as the Origin Path and then call the api by going to www.example.com/api?

Comment: Yes, It should work. Note: take care of cache by cache-control header or TTLs.

Comment: don't add origin path, instead have the clients request with this path and match the cache behaviour.

Comment: Yep, I had to remove the origin path and then just add the path pattern to the behaviour tab to invoke the origin and it works. I'll attach an answer later with my steps. Thanks for your help James.